# Rails 4 - using 'where' to search & display certain users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a little stuck and any help or advise would be much appreciated.

I would like to display only users that have a resume but I am unsure how
- I have the below codings in my file - your advise & help will be much appreciated.

in my user/index.html

```
<% users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.resume.summary  %>
<% end %>
```

schema

```
  create_table "resumes", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "summary"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
```

models

```
user.rb
has_one :resume

resume.rb
belongs_to :user
```

I would like to do a search that only displays users with a resume.
I tried the below but no luck

```
<% users.where(resume_id: !nil).each do |user| %>
  <%= user.resume.summary  %>
<% end %>

<% users.where("resume IS NOT NULL != ?", "").each do |user| %>
  <%= user.resume.summary  %>
<% end %>
```

I tried writing as a scope but no luck

```
user.rb file
scope :users_with_resumes, -> {where(['resume != ?', nil])}

users/index.html.erb file
<% @users.users_with_resumes.each do |userj| %>
  <%= user.resume.summary  %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close to hitting the mark, but your syntax in your attempts is slightly off:

```
# This won't work because you're now searching for the value !nil (or 'true')
<% users.where(resume_id: !nil).each do |user| %>
  <%= user.resume.summary  %>
<% end %>

# This is a double negative, syntactically incorrect, and referencing resume instead of resume_id
<% users.where("resume IS NOT NULL != ?", "").each do |user| %>
  <%= user.resume.summary  %>
<% end %>
```

You should instead use one of the following:

```
users.where.not(resume_id: nil)

users.where("resume_id IS NOT NULL")
```

I think you'll find either of those statements will serve your purpose whether scoped or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The below code displays only users with resumes

> Association

```
user has_one resume
resume belongs_to user
```

> schema

```
 create_table "resumes", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "summary"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
```

> user.rb

```
scope :users_with_resumes, -> {where("id in (select user_id from resumes)")}

or instead of a scope you can write a method

def self.users_with_resumes
 where("id in (select user_id from resumes)")
end
```

> users/index.html.erb [this display only users with a resume]

```
<% @users.users_with_resumes.each do |user| %>
 <%= user.resume.summary  %>
<% end %>
```